# xecvp: ./chk: Permission denied

Tags: xen

I'm trying to install Xen 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 10.10. 
When I run the "make world" it gives the following error at the end....

```
make -C check clean
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1/tools/check'
./chk clean
make[4]: execvp: ./chk: Permission denied
make[4]: *** [clean] Error 127
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1/tools/check'
make[3]: *** [subdir-clean-check] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1/tools'
make[2]: *** [subdirs-clean] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1/tools'
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1'
make: *** [world] Error 2
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
make[4]: execvp: ./chk: Permission denied
```

seems to indicate you have a permission problem.  Are you running the make command as the same user who untarred the distribution?  What does `ls -la /home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1/tools/check/chk` say? I suspect it will show that file is owned by a different user (not `hirantha`) and it's not executable by hirantha.

You may be able to fix this by running

```
cd /home/hirantha/xen-4.0.1
sudo make
```

to run the make command as root instead of hirantha.

Answer (score 0):

For reference: I encountered this error due to permissions errors caused by trying to make from a NTFS partition. Untarring to /tmp/ resolved the problem.